# What is a "pretty and proper OO" way for handling sessions and authentication?

Tags: php, oop, session, authentication

Is coupling these two concepts a bad approach?

As of right now I'm delegating all session handling and whether or not a user desires to logout in my config.inc file. As I was writing my Auth class I started wondering whether or not my Auth class should be taking care of most of the logic in my config.inc. Regardless, I'm sure there's a more elegant way of handling this...

Here is what I have in my config.inc (also a large chunk of this code is based on a reply I found on SO except I can't find the source ._.):

```
ini_set('session.name', 'SID');

# session management
session_set_cookie_params(24*60*60); // set SID cookie lifetime
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['LOGOUT']) {
    session_destroy(); // destroy session data
    $_SESSION = array(); // destroy session data sanity check
    setcookie('SID', '', time() - 24*60*60); // destroy session cookie data
    #header('Location: '.DOCROOT);
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['SID_AUTH'])) { // verify user has authenticated

    if (!isset($_SESSION['SID_CREATED'])) {
        $_SESSION['SID_CREATED'] = time();
    } elseif (time() - $_SESSION['SID_CREATED'] > 6*60*60) {
        // session started more than 6 hours ago
        session_regenerate_id(); // reset SID value
        $_SESSION['SID_CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['SID_MODIFIED']) && (time() - $_SESSION['SID_MODIFIED'] > 12*60*60)) {
        // last request was more than 12 hours ago
        session_destroy(); // destroy session data
        $_SESSION = array(); // destroy session data sanity check
        setcookie('SID', '', time() - 24*60*60); // destroy session cookie data
    }

    $_SESSION['SID_MODIFIED'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
}
```

Comment: See this blog:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/  and the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq .  Specifically, your question is like this example:  "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”"  Your question is a good one, but you may want to entertain it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com which is related to subjective questions like these.

Comment: Okay, so delete and cross-post there?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind frameworks and look for more elegant way, look into [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.introduction.html) - it handles authentication and all session stuff that needs to be done under the hood. It allows you to plug in either session storage or any other mechanism for the auth data persistence.

So I would say authentication and storage should not be tightly coupled but the former has to define interface to the latter and take session as an option.